# is it possible to display view name on a chart?

Tags: charts, dynamics-crm-2011, filtering

We have a dashboard with some charts, and each chart has a corresponding view for filtering the data. Choosing different views filters the chart source data accordingly. 
Is it possible to display the view name somewhere on the chart? Currently, once the chart is printed out there's no way to tell how the data was filtered.

Comment: Are you viewing the chart from the view? If you are viewing the chart on a dashboard the view name is displayed below the chart name.

Comment: @Bvrce The chart is on a dashboard, but as I said the problem is when you print the chart out. We have users enlarging and printing out charts to take them to meetings as handouts, but have to hand-write the view name on each copy to remember what data it's showing.

Comment: Printing out Charts?  that's old school.  And it loses drill-down/through capabilities